How do I load a text file into Pandas that contains multiple lists?
I have a text file that I would like to load up into a Pandas dataframe and create some plots from.  The data is some GPS satellite data and contains information for multiple satellites in view for any given time epoch.
The text file that I have is in the following simplified structure:
1077, 473055000, 0, 1,['003','1C','0.002','0.003','38','-0.4']['003','1W','0.032','0.023','40','-0.4']['006','1C','0.124','0.333','19','-0.5']['006','1W','0.100','0.232','29','-0.6']
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,['003','1C','0.012','0.004','39','-0.5']['003','1W','0.042','0.025','41','-0.41']['006','1C','0.125','0.343','39','-0.53']['006','1W','0.110','0.234','39','-0.56']['006','5Q','0.330','0.234','36','-0.51']

What i would like to see in my dataframe, so that it can be plotted is as follows:
1077, 473055000, 0, 1,003,1C,0.002,0.003,38.5,-0.4
1077, 473055000, 0, 1,003,1W,0.032,0.023,40.6,-0.4
1077, 473055000, 0, 1,006,1C,0.124,0.333,19.2,-0.5
1077, 473055000, 0, 1,006,1W,0.100,0.232,29.3,-0.6
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,003,1C,0.012,0.004,39.2,-0.5
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,003,1W,0.042,0.025,41.6,-0.41
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,006,1C,0.125,0.343,39.8,-0.53
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,006,1W,0.110,0.234,39.2,-0.56
1077, 473056000, 0, 1,006,5Q,0.330,0.234,36.4,-0.51

Just for clarification, the 473055000 and 473056000 are milliseconds from the start of the GPS week. I'll need to do a separate conversion to UTC, but that's a another issue. The values in brackets are from separate satellites (the 003 and 006 in the first value in the brackets), and from different message types from these satellites (the 1C, 1W and 5Q values, second value in the brackets).
Given the above dataset i have tried to load this up into a Python Pandas DataFrame using the following code:
import pandas as pd

file = r'D:\projects\test-data.csv'

df = pd.DataFrame(file,columns = ['id','time','steer','extclk','prn','msg','pseudoR','carrPh','A','CNR','B','C'])

print(df)

However, I get the following message:
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called.

Loading data from a csv file is quite straightforward usually, however, the data structure i have in this file complicates things a lot. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might achieve this?

You can fix your files with sed:
sed 's/\]$/\]"/; s/\[/"\[/' data.csv > data_fixed.csv

And then process them using this code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data_fixed.csv', header=None, names=['id','time','steer','extclk', 'arrays'])

df_arrays = df['arrays'].str.extractall(r"\[(.*?)\]")\
    .droplevel(1)\
    .squeeze(1)\
    .str.replace("'", '')\
    .str.split(',')\
    .apply(pd.Series)
df_arrays.columns = ['prn','msg','pseudoR','carrPh','A','CNR']

df_merged = df.drop(columns=['arrays']).join(df_arrays)
df_merged[['pseudoR','carrPh','A', 'CNR']] = df_merged.loc[:, ['pseudoR','carrPh','A', 'CNR']].map(pd.to_numeric)

     id       time  steer  extclk  prn msg  pseudoR  carrPh   A   CNR
0  1077  473055000      0       1  003  1C    0.002   0.003  38 -0.40
0  1077  473055000      0       1  003  1W    0.032   0.023  40 -0.40
0  1077  473055000      0       1  006  1C    0.124   0.333  19 -0.50
0  1077  473055000      0       1  006  1W    0.100   0.232  29 -0.60
1  1077  473056000      0       1  003  1C    0.012   0.004  39 -0.50
1  1077  473056000      0       1  003  1W    0.042   0.025  41 -0.41
1  1077  473056000      0       1  006  1C    0.125   0.343  39 -0.53
1  1077  473056000      0       1  006  1W    0.110   0.234  39 -0.56
1  1077  473056000      0       1  006  5Q    0.330   0.234  36 -0.51


You have several issues to address.  First, the file is not a CSV format.  It is close to one, but a standard CSV reader will not parse it correctly.  Second, loading a file into a Pandas data frame is accomplished using one of the read_<format> methods: read_csv, read_json, read_feather, etc.
To use pd.DataFrame, we have to pass in data that is already in Python.  To get your data our of your file, you will need to use a custom parser.  After parsing the data, then you can put it into a data frame.
def parse_bracket(b_str:str):
    b = b_str.strip('[]').replace("'", '')
    prn, msg, ps, c, A, CNR = b.split(',')
    return {
        'prn': prn,
        'msg': msg,
        'pseudoR': float(ps),
        'carrPh': float(c),
        'A': float(A),
        'CNR': float(CNR)
    }

def parse_row(row: str):
    id_, time, steer, extclk, brackets = row.split(',', 4)
    id_, time, steer, extclk = map(int, [id_, time, steer, extclk])
    d = {'id': id_, 'time': time, 'steer': steer, 'extclk': extclk}
    data = []
    for bracket in brackets.split(']['):
        data.append(d | parse_bracket(bracket))
    return data

with open('D:/projects/test-data.csv') as fp:
    data = []
    for row in fp:
        data.extend(parse_row(row))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Here is the content of df:
     id       time  steer  extclk  prn msg  pseudoR  carrPh     A   CNR
0  1077  473055000      0       1  003  1C    0.002   0.003  38.0 -0.40
1  1077  473055000      0       1  003  1W    0.032   0.023  40.0 -0.40
2  1077  473055000      0       1  006  1C    0.124   0.333  19.0 -0.50
3  1077  473055000      0       1  006  1W    0.100   0.232  29.0 -0.60
4  1077  473056000      0       1  003  1C    0.012   0.004  39.0 -0.50
5  1077  473056000      0       1  003  1W    0.042   0.025  41.0 -0.41
6  1077  473056000      0       1  006  1C    0.125   0.343  39.0 -0.53
7  1077  473056000      0       1  006  1W    0.110   0.234  39.0 -0.56
8  1077  473056000      0       1  006  5Q    0.330   0.234  36.0 -0.51

